# Need to start again at a certain point in java

Tags: java, loops

I'm really new to java, and just programming in general. I am trying to make a simple "story game".
I want the program to start again where I commented "starting again point `if walk.equals("b")` (second time)"

Here is my code:
P.S. sorry if it is poorly written

```
import java.util.*;

public class leikur1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) { 

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("|---------Welcome to the adventure------------|"); 
     System.out.println("Please enter Name"); // inputs name
     String nafn = scan.nextLine();
     nafn = nafn.toLowerCase();

     System.out.println("Gender, male or female");
     String kyn = scan.nextLine();
     kyn = kyn.toLowerCase();
        while((!kyn.equals("male")) && (!kyn.equals("female")) )  //bara haegt ad velja male eda female
        {
          System.out.println("That is not valid input" );
          kyn = scan.nextLine();
          kyn = kyn.toLowerCase();
        }


     System.out.println("Are you ready for the adventure"); 
     String leikur = scan.nextLine();
     leikur = leikur.toLowerCase(); 
         while((!leikur.equals("yes")) && (!leikur.equals("no")) )  //impossible to input something else than male or female
         {
           System.out.println("That is not valid input" );
           leikur = scan.nextLine();
           leikur = leikur.toLowerCase();
         } 
     if(leikur.equals("no"))
          {
            System.out.println("Thank you anyway"); //if input = no program ends
           }


     // if input = yes the game begins
     else
          {
           System.out.println("Write Start to begin or Quit to exit"); 
     String start = scan.nextLine();
     start = start.toLowerCase();

     String gender;  
     if(kyn.equals("male"))
          {
          gender = "he"; 
          }
    else
    {
      gender = "she";
              }



     while((!start.equals("start")) && (!start.equals("quit")) )
     {
       System.out.println("That is not valid input" );
       start = scan.nextLine();
       start = start.toLowerCase();
     }


     if(start.equals("start")) 
     {
     System.out.println("Walking instructions: left - l    right - r     forward - f      back -  b    down - d     up - u\n");  
     System.out.println(nafn + " is in a abandoned house late at night, stuck in the basement with no light.\n");
     System.out.println("In wich way should " + gender + " go to find his way to the stairs?"   ); **// starting again point if walk.equals("b") (second time)**
     String walk = scan.nextLine();
     walk = walk.toLowerCase();

     //////////
     while((!walk.equals("f")) && (!walk.equals("b")) ) // not possible bcus of walls or no stairs
     {
       System.out.println("That is not possible" );
       walk = scan.nextLine();
     }


     if(walk.equals("f"))
          {
           System.out.println("Great choice, " + gender + " found the stairs right away. Should"+gender+" go upstairs or go back?" );
          }

     else if (walk.equals("b"))
          {
           System.out.println("Oh boy! " + nafn +" got stuck in a beartrap and died... GAME OVER" );
          }
   /////////

     walk = scan.nextLine();
     while(!walk.equals("u") && !walk.equals("b") )
     {
       System.out.println("That is not possible" );
       walk = scan.nextLine();
     }


     if(walk.equals("u"))
     {
     System.out.println("Excelent!" + nafn + " is now upstairs" );
     }

     **else if(walk.equals("b") )
     {
     System.out.println("Now " + nafn + " is at stage 1 again" );
     }**
     //////////////



     // code 4 the game should be here above
     }
     else if(start.equals("quit"))
     {
     System.out.println("Thank you anyway");
     }

    }        

  }
}
```

Comment: try to come up with simple example ? try to narrow than your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to repeat your content, a `while` loop is sufficient

```
boolean continue = true;

while(continue)
{
   else if(walk.equals("b") )
   {
       System.out.println("Now " + nafn + " is at stage 1 again" );
       continue = true;
   }
   else if(start.equals("quit"))
   {
       System.out.println("Thank you anyway");
       continue = false;
   }
}
```

---

the reason I'm using the variable `continue` is to better illustrate the while loop.  you can also use `while(true)`, which will normally loop forever. to skip to the beginning of the next iteration you use `continue;` and to break out, you can use `break`

```
while(true)
{
   else if(walk.equals("b") )
   {
       System.out.println("Now " + nafn + " is at stage 1 again" );
       continue;
   }
   else if(start.equals("quit"))
   {
       System.out.println("Thank you anyway");
       break;
   }
}
```

---

If you **really** wanted to take your coding to the next level, you could take a more data-driven approach, and have a data model to define your game.  The following is a sample data model in xml

```
<Places>
    <Place name="YourRoom" text="You are in your room. Where would you like to go?">
        <Option text="Enter the hallway." result="Hallway"></Option>
    </Place>
    <Place name="Hallway" text="You are in the hallway. Where would you like to go?">
        <Option text="Go to your room" result="YourRoom"></Option>
    </Place>
</Places>
```

And then you'd write your program something like this

**pseudocode:**

```
xmlElement currentRoom = // get starting element

while(true)
{
    print(currentRoom.Attributes[text])
    for(int i=0; i<currentRoom.Elements.length; i++)
    {
        print(currentRoom.Elements[i] + "type " + i+1;
    }
    int choice = getInt();
    int result = currentRoom.Elements[choice].result;
    currentRoom GetElementWithName(result);   
}
```

Comment: ,,If you just want to repeat your content, a while loop is sufficient"              
sorry for not being clear enough, I meant that  if(walk.equals("b")) then I want to go back to the beginning of the game or to be exact this point

System.out.println("In wich way should " + gender + " go to find his way to the stairs?"   );

Comment: @AndriHeiðberg using the `continue` keyword skips right to the beginning of the loop

Comment: do you know where I can find a tutorial to learn how to make data models?

Comment: @AndriHeiðberg no, I don't offhand, but I just googled this:  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should rather learn Java, OOP and other base constructs. If you really insist, you can use [labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) (to be honest since the advent of structured programming, in the sixties people try not to use GOTO anymore... but if you want to fail a job interview go ahead ;-) )

```
// ...
// label is your label, you can use any text
label:{ 
  // ...
  // here is your GOTO
  break label;
}
```

Side note : it works like a charm, but please don't do it (or at least don't say I'm the one who told you about labels) !